# Echo command output "-n" in a file from Makefile

Tags: makefile, echo, zsh

I have a Makefile that has this kind of command:

```
browserify:
    rm -rf ./dist
    mkdir dist
    # Browserify
    echo -n "/* ${NPM_PACKAGE} ${NPM_VERSION} ${GITHUB_PROJ} */" \
        > dist/pica.js
```

So when I do `make browserify` it should output the comment to the top of the file without `\n`. But for some reasons... the output looks like this

```
-n /* package 0.0.0 */
...more things...
```

I'm using zsh on osx.

Comment: -n is a bash extension, i think it works with dash

Comment: @rhubarbdog: echo is not a bash builtin, but a standalone program. But there are different implementations; Linux usually has the one from the Coreutils package, other Unices have a different one.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (GNUMake 3.81). The echo works correctly when called on the command line and redirected to a file; it works correctly when invoked in the makefile to write to standard output; it fails only when invoked in the makefile and redirected to a file.

Comment: @lxg While there is an standalone program called named `echo`, `bash` also implements it as a built-in command for efficiency. (Compare the output of `type echo` with `type $(which echo)`).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter what shell you are using.  Make will *always* use `/bin/sh` as the shell it invokes (unless you specifically set the `SHELL` make variable to something else).  Think what a disaster it would be if make used whatever shell the user was using to invoke recipes!

On many GNU/Linux systems, `/bin/sh` is actually a link to `bash`.  On other GNU/Linux systems, `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash` which is a small, POSIX-standard shell without all the extensions `bash` uses (`dash` is good for running portable shell scripts fast, but not good for a user's interactive shell as it's missing too many expected features).  On non-GNU-based systems (like OSX) `/bin/sh` might be `ksh` or something else even.

There is no portable, standard way to invoke `echo` in such a way that it doesn't print the trailing newline.  There is an `echo` program, and different ones work differently.  Many shells, including `bash` and `zsh` also have an `echo` built-in to the shell:

```
$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
```

and these versions of `echo` also work differently than the program `echo`.  Some versions have no way to suppress newlines.  Some use the `-n` flag.  Some use `\c` at the end to suppress printing the newline.  Some support a combination of them.

The short answer is that if you want to print a line in the shell without a newline in a portable and reliable way, you should use the `printf` program to do it, not `echo`:

```
browserify:
        rm -rf ./dist
        mkdir dist
        # Browserify
        printf %s "/* ${NPM_PACKAGE} ${NPM_VERSION} ${GITHUB_PROJ} */" \
            > dist/pica.js
```

Comment: Just a question, it works but the `printf` command is widely available and installed. I'm asking because in at least 7 years, I never really heard about it or never seen it being used.  If there is a better way to output text to a file it could be even better.

Comment: I don't understand your comment; maybe you meant to say "the `printf` command is _NOT_ widely available and installed"?  If so I assure you that's not true.  `printf` was added to the POSIX standard in Issue 4 which was released in 1992.  Regardless of whether you've heard of it or not, it's been many, many years since I've run across a UNIX system which didn't provide it.  As for outputting text, `echo` is fine for outputting text... but there is no better/simpler alternative for outputting text _without a trailing newline_, which is what you asked for.